# Gramex redis cache set memory error in azure instance

Tags: caching, redis, gramex

I am unable to set memory through config for redis azure instance in gramex
It gives this error:
redis.exceptions.ResponseError: unknown command `CONFIG`, with args beginning with: `SET`, `maxmemory`, `1000000000`

[image reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nc9bC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the size as zero. This will ignore the size limit. However, please ensure that you have set the `maxmemory-policy` as `volatile-lru` in the redis instance. This solution would require gramex >= 1.67